# Setting and Using Variables in MySQL scripts

Tags: mysql, variables

MSSQL DBA here, I know how to do the following in TSQL, I am wondering if the same can be done in MySQL. Basically, set a variable and be able to use it throughout a script. MySQL docs have gotten me only so far, looking for some veteran MySQL devs/dbas for some detail. Thanks.

```
SET @newuser := `'usr652'@'%.domain.com'`;
SET @pw := `'ge?jJ!ARxbz$qiC6n'`;

CREATE USER @newuser IDENTIFIED BY @pw;

ALTER USER IF EXISTS
 @newuser PASSWORD EXPIRE;

GRANT USAGE ON `POP%`.* TO @newuser;

GRANT SELECT ON `POP%`.* TO @newuser;

SHOW GRANTS FOR @newuser;
```

Comment: Is there a problem with that?  That assignment looks fine.  Do you get an error?  I think sometimes mySQL can be funny about using variables in certain commands, and obviously I can't run that script to see what happens.

Comment: actually, you might want to replace the backticks with double quotes.  This works fine in a fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8c0e6d80ac00eb0b21d32980c8eaca2, and if you are having trouble with a particular command failing because it doesn't want to use the variables I think you can prepare a statement from them using string concatenation and execute that.

Comment: @ChrisStrickland, thank you using the double quotes helped

Comment: was that the whole issue?